# SQL Count and Group By issue

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I have a table Mbr that contains 3 fields, `GroupType`, `LeaderID`, and `MemberID`. Basically, all the members in an organization are divided up into these groups, identified by their **leader's unique ID** (`LeaderID`). Each member record also has their own `MemberID`, and the leaders themselves have a unique `MemberID` as well.  The `GroupType` just designates whether the group a member is in which is considered a `Large`, `Small`, or `Individual` group.

I need to find out how many groups of each `GroupType` contain a certain number of members.
For example:

- How many Large groups contain 6 members, 7 members, 8 members, 9 and so on.
- How many Small Groups contain 2 members, 3 members, 4 members and 5 members
- How many Individual groups there are.

Is it possible make a query to get a Count of the unique `MemberID`'s for each `group`, and then get a `COUNT` of how many `LeaderID`'s have a certain number of members associated to them?

Comment: please identify which DBMS system are you using

Comment: Some sample data and sample output go a long way here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Since you are not specifying which `DBMS` you are using, I tried to do a basic query. In `SQLServer` or `Oracle` this can be much more elegant.

I'm assuming that a given `Member` can be `Leader` leader of only one `Group` if that is correct,

Question #1:

```
SELECT GroupType, NumberOfMembers, COUNT(LeaderID) AS NumberOfGroups
FROM (
    SELECT GroupType, LeaderID, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfMembers
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY GroupType, LeaderID
) AS InnerGrouping
GROUP BY GroupType, NumberOfMembers
ORDER BY GroupType, NumberOfMembers
```

Question #2:

```
SELECT UniqueMemberIDPerGroup, COUNT(LeaderID) AS NumberOfLeaderID 
FROM ( 
    SELECT LeaderID, COUNT(DISTINCT MemberID) AS UniqueMemberIDPerGroup
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY LeaderID
) AS InnerGrouping
GROUP BY UniqueMemberIDPerGroup
```

Comment: A MemberID might be listed more than once, but I'd like to only count the unique occurrences. And it is just one question, sorry if the last part was worded a little awkwardly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can write some complex query with several subqueries to create a query to give you what you want, but I personally like more straightforward methods. In this case, it would be using some temp tables to store intermediate values. I would first group by several columns (that you are going to use as criterias) with count being the value for the query. I would then store these into a temp table and finally create a query to utilize the temp table to give you the results that you are looking for.